# Page not refreshing Cli commands not working

Tags: magento2

Flush magento or clean magento CLI commands not working
page not refreshing or not refresh data and pages.
Any idea ???? please help

Comment: Please give us more details. Your question is not clear to me at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the log files for exact issue

```
var/log/exception 

var/log/debug
```